# Erro importação de csv com fopen

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma importação de csv com PHP parar inserir direto em banco MySql, estou usando a função fopen, que me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING) in ... on line 6
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<?php

include_once('dados.php');

 // Abre o Arquvio no Modo r (para leitura)
 $arquivo =  fopen ('teste.csv','r');

 // Lê o conteúdo do arquivo
 while(!feof($arquivo))
 {
  // Pega os dados da linha
  $linha = fgets($arquivo, 1024);

  // Divide as Informações das celular para poder salvar
  $dados = explode(';', $linha);

  // Verifica se o Dados Não é o cabeçalho ou não esta em branco
  if($dados[0] != 'Data' && !empty($linha))
  {

  try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$nomebanco, $username, $password);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO atendimento (data, hora, id_atendente, id_representante, funcionario, id_sistema,' .
      'cliente, id_categoria, assunto, motivo, resolucao)'.
      'VALUES(:data, :hora, :atendente, :representante, :funcionario, :sistema, '.
      ':cliente, :categoria, :assunto, :motivo, :resolucao)');

      $stmt->execute(array(
        ':data' => $dados[0],
            ':hora' => $dados[1],
            ':atendente' => $dados[2],
            ':representante' => $dados[3],
            ':funcionario' => $dados[4],
            ':sistema' => $dados[5],
            ':cliente' => $dados[6],
            ':categoria' => $dados[7],
            ':assunto' => $dados[8],
            ':motivo' => $dados[9],
            ':resolucao' => $dados[10]
      ));

      echo $stmt->rowCount();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
 }

 // Fecha arquivo aberto
 fclose($arquivo);
}
?>
```

Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido. O erro estava na linha.

```
$arquivo =  fopen ('teste.csv','r');
```

Forma correta:

```
$arquivo =  fopen ("atendimento.csv","r");
```